# Scala Match Error during macro expansion

Tags: scala, macros, pattern-matching

Hi I am trying to convert mathematical expressions into the Binary expressions. 
e.g;

```
2 + x turns into BinOp("+",Number(2.0),Var(x))
```

I want to make those during the compile time so I used macros in scala. Here is my macro implementation;

```
class ExpressionImplicitsImpl(val c: Context)  {


  def expr(exprTree: c.Expr[AnyRef]) : c.Expr[Expression] = {
    import c.universe._

    exprTree.tree match {
      case Ident(TermName(x)) => reify{Var(x.toString)}
      case Literal(Constant(a)) => reify{Number(a.asInstanceOf[Double])}
      case q"$a + $b" => reify{BinOp("+", expr(a.asInstanceOf).splice, expr(b.asInstanceOf).splice)}
      case q"$a * $b" => reify{BinOp("*", expr(a.asInstanceOf).splice, expr(b.asInstanceOf).splice)}
    }
  }
}
```

`BinOp`, `Var` and `Number` classes are `case classes` and extends `Expression` class. But this is not so important in that case.

My actual class which uses this macro is

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    import ExpressionImplicits._
    val e1 = expr { (x: Double) => (x * 6) + (8.0 * x) }
    println(e1) // I expect BinOp(+,BinOp(*,Var(x),Number(6.0)),BinOp(*,Number(8.0),Var(x)))
}
```

However, I get a matching error. I am kind of new pattern matching and this is my second macro trial. So if you could give me educative examples and simple explanations would be great.

Comment: In your example you're passing a lambda, which you don't seem to handle in your macro

Comment: Well I also tried to add it as a case, but I guess we can't handle the lambdas with `match` ? How can I handle this case?

Comment: lambdas have their own AST, so you can match on that. Try adding a default case and printing its AST. It will print the case you failed to match, helping you in debugging this. Something like `case t => showRaw(t)`